Typing on TextInput is executes two functions instead just one of this on iOS devices | React Native Expo
I am currently working on a unit conversion calculator in React Native + Expo Go. Handle the value of each TextInput to convert hectares to m/2. When typing in one TextInput the result will be set in the other TextInput and do the calculation vice versa. This works correctly on Android devices but not on iOS devices.

The problem is when I typing on iOS devices the caculation execute 2 times, changing input's values on both TextInputs instead of one of this.

package.json

"expo": "~50.0.8",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.4",
"react-hook-form": "^7.49.2",
"typescript": "^5.1.3"


Parent component:

const unitConverter = () => {
  const [convertionSelected, setConvertionSelected] = useState("area");
  const [listOfUnits, setListOfUnits] = useState(converters.area);
  const [showUnitsModal, setShowUnitsModal] = useState(false);
  const [unitNameFrom, setUnitNameFrom]: useStateProp<null | string> =
    useState(null);
  const [unitNameTo, setUnitNameTo]: useStateProp<null | string> =
    useState(null);
  const [selectClicked, setSelectClicked]: useStateProp<null | string> =
    useState(null);
  const [unitSelectedTop, setUnitSelectedTop]: useStateProp<null | item> =
    useState(null);
  const [unitSelectedBottom, setUnitSelectedBottom]: useStateProp<null | item> =
    useState(null);
  const [valueTop, setValueTop] = useState("0")
  const [valueBottom, setValueBottom] = useState("0")
  const [isScrollEnabled, setIsScrollEnabled] = useState(false);

  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null)

  const {
    control,
    setError,
    formState: { errors },
    clearErrors,
    reset,
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      inputTop: "",
      inputBottom: ""
    },
  });

  /**
   * Setting type of converter
   *
   * @param converter unit converter, area, peso, volumen
   */
  const handleConverterType = (converter: string) => {
    setConvertionSelected(converter);

    if (converter === "area") setListOfUnits(converters.area);
    if (converter === "peso") setListOfUnits(converters.peso);
    if (converter === "volumen") setListOfUnits(converters.volumen);

    if (unitNameFrom) setUnitNameFrom(null);
    if (unitNameTo) setUnitNameTo(null);

    if (unitSelectedTop) setUnitSelectedTop(null);
    if (unitSelectedBottom) setUnitSelectedBottom(null);

    if (valueTop.length || valueBottom.length) {
      setValueTop("0");
      setValueBottom("0");
    }
  };

  /**
   * Handle units select modal visibility
   *
   * @param show handle select modal visibility
   * @param select handle if clicked on top or bottom buttons selects
   */
  const handleShowUnitsModal = (show: boolean, select: string = "") => {
    if (platform === "ios" && Keyboard.isVisible()) Keyboard.dismiss();

    setShowUnitsModal(show);
    setSelectClicked(select);
  };

  // handle unit selected
  const handleUnitSelected = (unit: item) => {
    if (selectClicked === "top") {
      if (showUnitsModal) handleShowUnitsModal(false);
      setUnitSelectedTop(unit);
      setUnitNameFrom(unit.option);
    }

    if (selectClicked === "bottom") {
      if (showUnitsModal) handleShowUnitsModal(false);
      setUnitSelectedBottom(unit);
      setUnitNameTo(unit.option);
    }

    if (JSON.stringify(errors) != "{}") {
      clearErrors("inputTop");
      clearErrors("inputBottom");
    }
  };

  // Handling if input value is a number
  const handleIsNotNum = (input: string) => {
    if (input === "top") {
      setError("inputTop", {
        type: "required",
        message: "Ingrese un valor numérico válido",
      });
    } else {
      setError("inputBottom", {
        type: "required",
        message: "Ingrese un valor numérico válido",
      });
    }
  };
  
  // Handling useFrom's clearErrors for inputs
  const handleClearErrors = (input: clearErrorsProp) => {
    if (errors[input]?.message) clearErrors(input);
  }

  /**
   * Handle input's value format it a thoundsands, and/or centecimals
   * 
   * @param num {string} input value
   * @returns formated input value as latam coin
   */
  const formatNumber = (num: string) => {
    if (num === ",") return "0,"
    if (num.length === 2) {
      if (num[0] === "0" && ONLY_NUMBER_REGEX.test(num[1])) num = num[1]
    }

    num = num.replaceAll(".", "");

    if (num.includes(",")) {
      const [integers, decimals] = num.split(",")
      const newDecimals = decimals.length >= 4 ? decimals.slice(0, 4) : decimals

      if (newDecimals.length === 4 && newDecimals.split("").every(num => num === "0")) return integers

      return integers.replace(FORMAT_NUM_REGEX, ".").concat(",").concat(newDecimals)
    } else {
      return num.replace(FORMAT_NUM_REGEX, ".")
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handle convertion result value format it a thoundsands, and/or centecimals
   * 
   * @param num {string} convertion result value
   * @returns convertion result value as latam coin
   */
  const formatConvertionResult = (num: string) => {
    if (num.includes(".")) {
      const [integers, decimals] = num.split(".")
      const formatIntegers = integers.replace(FORMAT_NUM_REGEX, ".")

      // greater than or equals to 4 decimals
      if (decimals.length >= 4) {
        const splitDecimals = decimals.slice(0, 4)
        const areZeros = splitDecimals.split("").every(num => num === "0")

        if (areZeros) return formatIntegers

        return `${formatIntegers},${splitDecimals}`;
      }

      // less than to 4 decimals
      const splitDecimals = decimals.slice(0, 3)
      const areZeros = splitDecimals.split("").every(num => num === "0")

      if (areZeros) return formatIntegers

      return `${formatIntegers},${splitDecimals}`
    }

    return num.replace(FORMAT_NUM_REGEX, ".")
  } 

  /**
   * Calculate values to get convertion by units settled
   * 
   * @param num 
   */
  const settingValueToTop = (num: string = "") => {
    num = num.length ? num : valueBottom;
    num = num.replaceAll(".", "");
    num = num.includes(",") ? num.replace(",", ".") : num;

    const unitCurrent = units[convertionSelected][unitSelectedBottom.name][unitSelectedTop.name];
    const total = parseFloat(num) * unitCurrent;
    const formatTotal = formatConvertionResult(total.toString())

    setValueTop(formatTotal);
  }

  /**
   * Calculate values to get convertion by units settled
   * 
   * @param num 
   */
  const settingValueToBottom = (num: string = "") => {
    num = num.length ? num : valueTop;
    num = num.replaceAll(".", "");
    num = num.includes(",") ? num.replace(",", ".") : num;

    const unitCurrent = units[convertionSelected][unitSelectedTop.name][unitSelectedBottom.name];
    const total = parseFloat(num) * unitCurrent;
    const formatTotal = formatConvertionResult(total.toString())

    setValueBottom(formatTotal);
  }

  // Input Top handler
  const onChangeInputTop = (num: string) => {
    console.log("top")
    console.log(num)
    if (num == "") {
      if (valueBottom !== "0") setValueBottom("0")
      handleClearErrors("inputTop")
      return setValueTop("0")
    }

    if (num === ".") return handleIsNotNum("bottom");
    if (!NUMBER_REGEX.test(num)) return handleIsNotNum("top");
    handleClearErrors("inputTop")

    const value = formatNumber(num);
    setValueTop(value);

    if (unitSelectedBottom != null && unitSelectedTop != null) {
      settingValueToBottom(value);
    }
  }

  // Input Bottom handler
  const onChangeInputBottom = (num: string) => {
    console.log("bottom")
    console.log(num)
    if (num == "") {
      if (valueTop !== "0") setValueTop("0");
      handleClearErrors("inputBottom")
      return setValueBottom("0");
    }

    if (num === ".") return handleIsNotNum("bottom");
    if (!NUMBER_REGEX.test(num)) return handleIsNotNum("bottom");
    handleClearErrors("inputBottom")

    const value = formatNumber(num);
    setValueBottom(value);
    
    if (unitSelectedBottom != null && unitSelectedTop != null) {
      settingValueToTop(value);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handle scrollView's scroll to enable it
   */
  const onPressInInput = () => {
    if (!isScrollEnabled) setIsScrollEnabled(true)
  }

  /**
   * Handle scrollView's scroll to disable it
   * when keyboard did hide, view will scroll till top in iOS devices
   */
  Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => {
    setIsScrollEnabled(false)
    if (platform === "ios") {
      scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({
        y: 0,
        animated: false
      })
    }
  });

  /**
   * Handle inputs values when unit top or bottom were changes
   * and setting value unit convertion to top or bottom
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (unitSelectedTop != null && unitSelectedBottom != null) {
      if (valueBottom !== "0" && valueTop !== "0") return settingValueToBottom();
      if (valueBottom !== "0" && valueTop === "0") return settingValueToTop();
      if (valueBottom === "0" && valueTop !== "0") return settingValueToBottom();
    }
  }, [unitSelectedTop]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (unitSelectedTop != null && unitSelectedBottom != null) {
      if (valueBottom !== "0" && valueTop !== "0") return settingValueToTop();
      if (valueBottom !== "0" && valueTop === "0") return settingValueToTop();
      if (valueBottom === "0" && valueTop !== "0") return settingValueToBottom();
    }
  }, [unitSelectedBottom]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <ScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        overScrollMode="never"
        scrollEnabled={isScrollEnabled}
        bounces={false}
        automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets={true}
        // onTouchEnd={onPressOutInput}
        style={styles.scrollview}
      >
        <View style={styles.containerBody}>
          <View style={styles.bodyTop}>
            <HeaderTools />
            <ToolsNavbar
              convertionSelected={convertionSelected}
              handleConverter={handleConverterType}
            />
            <InputTopConverterUnit
              control={control}
              unitNameFrom={unitNameFrom}
              valueTop={valueTop}
              handleShowUnitsModal={handleShowUnitsModal}
              onChangeInputTop={onChangeInputTop}
              onPressInInput={onPressInInput}
            />
            <IconConverterUnit />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.bodyBottom, { marginTop: platform === "ios" ? "5%" : "10%" }]}>
            <InputBottomConverterUnit
              control={control}
              unitNameTo={unitNameTo}
              valueBottom={valueBottom}
              handleShowUnitsModal={handleShowUnitsModal}
              onChangeInputBottom={onChangeInputBottom}
              onPressInInput={onPressInInput}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>

      <ModalUnits
        visible={showUnitsModal}
        listOfUnits={listOfUnits}
        unitSelectedTop={unitSelectedTop}
        unitSelectedBottom={unitSelectedBottom}
        handleShowUnitsModal={handleShowUnitsModal}
        handleUnitSelected={handleUnitSelected}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};


Inputs

type propsTop = {
  control: control;
  unitNameFrom: null | string;
  valueTop: string;
  handleShowUnitsModal: (show: boolean, select: string) => void;
  onChangeInputTop: (e: any) => void;
  onPressInInput: () => void;
};

export const InputTopConverterUnit: FC<propsTop> = ({
  control,
  valueTop,
  unitNameFrom,
  handleShowUnitsModal,
  onChangeInputTop,
  onPressInInput,
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={"inputTop"}
      control={control}
      rules={{
        required: "Ingrese un valor",
      }}
      render={({ fieldState: { error } }) => {
        return (
          <View style={[styles.containerInput, { marginTop: "3%" }]}>
            <UnitsSelect
              clickOn="top"
              onPress={handleShowUnitsModal}
              unitName={unitNameFrom}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={[
                styles.inputValue,
                {
                  paddingHorizontal: valueTop.length ? "10%" : "40%",
                },
              ]}
              keyboardType={"numeric"}
              cursorColor={"#123021"}
              onChangeText={onChangeInputTop}
              value={valueTop}
              multiline={true}
              onTouchStart={onPressInInput}
            />
            {error?.message && <Text>{error?.message}</Text>}
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

type propsBottom = {
  control: control;
  unitNameTo: null | string;
  valueBottom: string;
  handleShowUnitsModal: (show: boolean, select: string) => void;
  onChangeInputBottom: (num: string) => void;
  onPressInInput: () => void;
};

export const InputBottomConverterUnit: FC<propsBottom> = ({
  control,
  valueBottom,
  unitNameTo,
  handleShowUnitsModal,
  onChangeInputBottom,
  onPressInInput,
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={"inputBottom"}
      control={control}
      rules={{
        required: "Ingrese un valor",
      }}
      defaultValue={0}
      render={({ fieldState: { error } }) => {
        return (
          <View style={[styles.containerInput, { height: "70%" }]}>
            <UnitsSelect
              clickOn="bottom"
              onPress={handleShowUnitsModal}
              unitName={unitNameTo}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={[
                styles.inputValue,
                {
                  paddingHorizontal: valueBottom.length ? "10%" : "40%",
                },
              ]}
              keyboardType={"numeric"}
              cursorColor={"#123021"}
              onChangeText={onChangeInputBottom}
              onTouchStart={onPressInInput}
              value={valueBottom}
              multiline={true}
            />
            {error?.message && <Text>{error?.message}</Text>}
          </View>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};


Modal units for select

type item = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  option: string;
};

type props = {
  visible: boolean;
  listOfUnits: item[];
  unitSelectedTop: null | item;
  unitSelectedBottom: null | item;
  handleShowUnitsModal: (prop: boolean) => void;
  handleUnitSelected: (prop: item) => void
};

export const ModalUnits: FC<props> = ({
  visible,
  listOfUnits,
  unitSelectedTop,
  unitSelectedBottom,
  handleShowUnitsModal,
  handleUnitSelected,
}) => {
  const [newListOfUnits, setNewListOfUnits]: useStateProp<item[]> = useState(listOfUnits);

  const handleUnitsFromNewList = () => {
    if (unitSelectedBottom != null && unitSelectedTop != null) {
      const newList = listOfUnits.filter(unit => 
        unit.name != unitSelectedBottom.name &&
        unit.name != unitSelectedTop.name
      );

      return setNewListOfUnits(newList);
    }
  }

  // Filter list of units by unit selected
  useEffect(() => {
    if (unitSelectedTop != null && unitSelectedBottom == null) {
      const newList = listOfUnits.filter(unit => unit.name != unitSelectedTop.name);
      return setNewListOfUnits(newList);
    } else {
      handleUnitsFromNewList();
    }
  }, [unitSelectedTop]);

  // Filter list of units by unit selected
  useEffect(() => {
    if (unitSelectedBottom != null && unitSelectedTop == null) {
      const newList = listOfUnits.filter(unit => unit.name != unitSelectedBottom.name);
      return setNewListOfUnits(newList);
    } else {
      handleUnitsFromNewList();
    }
  }, [unitSelectedBottom])


  // Setting new list of units convertion
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewListOfUnits(listOfUnits)
  }, [listOfUnits])

  return (
    <Modal animationType="fade" transparent={true} visible={visible}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleShowUnitsModal(false)}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.containerModal}>
            <ScrollView overScrollMode="never">
              {newListOfUnits.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={item.name}
                    activeOpacity={0.5}
                    style={[
                      styles.btnUnit,
                      {
                        borderBottomWidth:
                          newListOfUnits.length !== index + 1 ? 1.5 : 0,
                        borderBottomColor:
                          newListOfUnits.length !== index + 1
                            ? "#123021"
                            : "none",
                      },
                    ]}
                    onPress={() => {
                      handleUnitSelected(item)
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text style={styles.txtUnit}>{item.option}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
              }
              )}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Modal>
  );
};


constants

type unitProps = {
  area: {}
  peso: {};
  volumen: {};
};

export const units: unitProps = {
  area: {
    ha: {
      m2: 10_000,
      mz: 1.419,
      tarea: 15.9,
    },
    m2: {
      ha: 0.000_1,
      mz: 0.000_141_964,
      tarea: 0.001_590_330,
    },
    mz: {
      ha: 0.7,
      m2: 7_000,
      tarea: 11.202_290,
    },
    tarea: {
      m2: 628.8,
      ha: 0.062_88,
      mz: 0.089_267,
    },
  },
  peso: {
    kg: {
      ton: 0.001,
      onzas: 35.274,
      libras: 2.204_62,
      tonLargas: 0.000_984_2,
      tonCortas: 0.001_102,
    },
    ton: {
      kg: 1_000,
      onzas: 35274.94,
      libras: 2204.62,
      tonLargas: 0.984_206,
      tonCortas: 1.102_3,
    },
    onzas: {
      kg: 0.028_35,
      ton: 0.000_028_349_5,
      libras: 0.062_5,
      tonLargas: 0.000_027_901_8,
      tonCortas: 0.000_031_25,
    },
    libras: {
      kg: 0.453_592,
      ton: 0.000_453_59,
      onzas: 16,
      tonLargas: 0.000_446_43,
      tonCortas: 0.000_5,
    },
    tonLargas: {
      kg: 1_016.05,
      onzas: 35_839.98,
      libras: 2_240,
      ton: 1.016,
      tonCortas: 1.12,
    },
    tonCortas: {
      kg: 907.18,
      onzas: 31_999.99,
      libras: 2_000,
      ton: 0.907_185,
      tonLargas: 0.892_857,
    },
    quintales: {
      kg: 1000,
      onzas: 3_527.396_2,
      libras: 220.462,
      ton: 0.1,
      tonLargas: 0.098_420_7,
      tonCortas: 0.110_231,
    },
  },
  volumen: {
    gal: { // EEUU - líquido
      lts: 3.785,
      ml: 3785.411_81,
    },
    lts: {
      gal: 0.264_172,
      ml: 1_000,
    },
    ml: {
      gal: 0.000_264_17,
      lts: 0.001,
    },
  },
};

type option = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  option: string;
};

type convertersProps = {
  area: option[];
  peso: option[];
  volumen: option[];
};

export const converters: convertersProps = {
  area: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "ha",
      option: "Hectareas (ha)",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "m2",
      option: "Metros cuadrados (m2)",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "mz",
      option: "Manzanas",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "tarea",
      option: "Tareas",
    },
  ],
  peso: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "kg",
      option: "Kilogramos (kg)",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "ton",
      option: "Toneladas (t)",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "onzas",
      option: "Onzas (oz)",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "tonLargas",
      option: "Toneladas Largas (lo tn)",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "tonCortas",
      option: "Toneladas Cortas (sh tn)",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "quintales",
      option: "Quintales (qm)",
    },
  ],
  volumen: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "gal",
      option: "Galon (gal)",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "lts",
      option: "Litros (lts)",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "ml",
      option: "Mililitros (ml)",
    },
  ],
};



Button for select unit to convert

type props = {
  clickOn: string;
  onPress: (open: boolean, clickOn: string) => void;
  unitName: null | string;
};

export const UnitsSelect: FC<props> = ({ clickOn, onPress, unitName }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      activeOpacity={0.7}
      style={styles.select}
      onPress={() => onPress(true, clickOn)}
    >
      <Text style={styles.txtUnit}>{unitName ?? "Seleccione unidad"}</Text>
      <CaretDown
        size={30}
        color="#123021"
        style={styles.iconCartetCircleDown}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

The function is simple, type a number in a TextInput to see the result in the other TextInput when the units to convert were selected.
